Does .NET Core IServiceScopeFactory child scope dispose transient services?
Whenever I need transient or scoped services inside a singleton or background service, I create them in a child scope:
using var serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var foo = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Foo>();

However I just noticed the API docs for CreateScope state:

Returns:
An IServiceScope controlling the lifetime of the scope. Once this is disposed, any scoped services that have been resolved from the IServiceScope.ServiceProvider will also be disposed.

Notice the wording "any scoped services".
Does that mean the scoped container does not dispose transient services (only scoped services)? I always thought a child container disposes everything it creates, and it's only the root container that holds on to transient references.
(I'm used to Autofac and some nuances between it and .NET DI are a little confusing.)

The guidance suggests that you shouldn't be registering IDisposables as transient to begin with.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. So a transient resolved from a child container will never be disposed, and over time eventually cause a memory leak?

It will be, but that means that your service can never be used as a dependency of a root service. The behavior is described in the docs which says by default the DI container will hold onto these references, and not Dispose() of them until ... or until the scope is disposed if they were resolved from a scope.. Instead of assuming how things are configured, why not make the service a scoped one?

If your service Y is resolved from the root, the transient Z will remain active for the duration of the application. The docs warn about this several times. If your service is itself a dependency of a root service X you'll end up with Z leaks. If it's a dependency of only scoped services, you won't.

What's the actual problem? From the phrase child container instead of scope I suspect you're trying to emulate the behavior of another DI library. Perhaps you already registered that other library as the actual DI provider and wonder how the rest of the DI infrastructure will behave?

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. I saw those docs but am still unsure. Let me make it more concrete: the service is a (singleton) background service, which has a (transient) dependency it resolves indirectly via an IServiceScopeFactory child scope (as in above code). That will lead to a memory leak?

That's no different than the original question and the docs already answer it. By default no. But the default could change, eg if you use a different container library with different semantics. In any case, if you ever try to use Foo in a different service, you'll have to be absolutely sure it's a scoped one, otherwise you'll have a leak. If the application is large, you can easily forget what is what on eg Friday at 4:50 pm. Better make things explicit

I just made a quick test and a transient service implementing IDisposable resolved within a scope gets disposed when that scope is disposed

Thanks @SirRufo. That's what I thought but wasn't sure. I guess the API docs shown above are poorly worded.

@Ionix I wasn't too, so I made this small test

I added a docs update request to the repo.

The wording in this part of the docs is not fully correct, at least for the default DI container - when scope is disposed it will dispose all dependencies which are owned/controlled/constructed by the scope itself. It is pretty easy to check:
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<MyDisposable>();
MyDisposable disposable;

using(var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
{
    disposable = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDisposable>();
}

Console.WriteLine(disposable.Disposed); // true

class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public bool Disposed { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Disposed = true;
    }
}

And to quote the docs:

When you register Transient services that implement IDisposable, by default the DI container will hold onto these references, and not Dispose() of them until the container is disposed when application stops if they were resolved from the container, or until the scope is disposed if they were resolved from a scope


Thanks! This is what I thought but the wording wasn't clear to me. My understanding was anything created by a child scope is disposed by that child scope.

The *.Abstractions docs can't say anything about edge cases. Different DI libraries can be used (like Autofac) and the behavior of the *.Abstractions namespace applies to all of them. There may not even be a scope concept in the DI library, and child containers are not scopes - you can't register services in scopes for example.

@PanagiotisKanavos fair point. Though arguably it can't say anything about scoped too, but says (or maybe this is requirement for implementers) =)

I added a docs update request to the repo.

The CreateScope docs talk about the scope. The Guidelines about the DI middleware itself. I suspect part of the weirdness ins due to the Enterprise Library/Unity containers which were a bit .... overengineered, but had to be supported because they were Microsoft's own libraries (at the time). There are both Transient and Container Transient lifecycles, and only Container Transient is actually disposed. Unity won't dispose Transient services when the scope ends

One follow-up if I may... The same docs state "Don't register IDisposable instances with a transient lifetime. Use the factory pattern instead." I assume that refers to the case where the transient services will be resolved from the root scope and thus remain for the lifetime of the app (through constructor injection?). But that advice does not apply when you intend to resolve from a child scope only (like you did above)?

@lonix - in short - yes. But you actually can't prevent somebody from resolving transient service from the root scope directly or indirectly.
